# How can I duplicate my code simply?

Tags: java, swing

I have the code below; I want it also want the code in the 'action performed' to happen when it is hovered over. Instead of copy and pasteing the code again and have twice as many times, Is there a way to set it easily?

The code:

```
private void btnGreenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Color btnGrn = new Color(159, 191, 143);          //Sets the colour to a class
    Color txtGrn = new Color(201, 255, 191);          //Sets the colour to a class
    Color txtGry = new Color(89, 89, 89);             //Sets the colour to a class
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(127,191,95)); //Sets background color to green
    btnConvert.setBackground(btnGrn);                 //Changes the colors to green
    btnReset.setBackground(btnGrn);                   //Changes the colors to green
    btnClose.setBackground(btnGrn);                   //Changes the colors to green
    btnInfo.setBackground(btnGrn);                    //Changes the colors to green
    txtIncome.setBackground(txtGrn);                  //Changes the colors to green
    txtPayable.setBackground(txtGrn);                 //Changes the colors to green
    txtStatus.setBackground(txtGrn);                  //Changes the colors to green
    txtIncome.setForeground(txtGry);                  //Changes the colors to grey
    txtPayable.setForeground(txtGry);                 //Changes the colors to grey
    txtStatus.setForeground(txtGry);                  //Changes the colors to grey
}
```

Note: I have 7 buttons that are all the same except for the color values.

Comment: Put the code into a method, and call that method when the button is clicked.

Comment: Just create either a method for this, and pass in the color values as the method parameters. More importantly, you appear to be getting the cart before the horse: you should learn at least the rudiments of Java before trying to code GUI's.

Comment: @christopher if you write that as an answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: I think you're actually asking two separate questions here.  You want to know how to get this code into two different actions - but you're also asking about calling it with other sets of colours.  That's really something quite different.

Comment: Umm, I think I'll be posting an answer to the second part of the question shortly, which will clarify my opinion.

Comment: @DavidWallace I believe you have it right, A method as of right now seems the way to go although I would like to see what you say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add an inner class to your panel class, to look after the colours, then create as many instances of it as you have colour schemes, including whatever colours you like.  Something like this.

This is all inside your panel class, by the way.  I'm not envisaging this as a stand-alone class in its own `.java` file; because it's entirely bound to the characteristics of the panel.  A more re-usable version of it would look a bit different.

```
private class ButtonColorScheme {
    final Color paneBackground;
    final Color buttonBackground;
    final Color textBackground;
    final Color textForeground;

    ButtonColorScheme(Color paneBackground, Color buttonBackground, Color textBackground, Color textForeground) {
        this.paneBackground = paneBackground;
        this.buttonBackground = buttonBackground;
        this.textBackground = textBackground;
        this.textForeground = textForeground;
    }

    void apply() {
        getContentPane().setBackground(paneBackground);
        btnConvert.setBackground(buttonBackground);
        btnReset.setBackground(buttonBackground);
        btnClose.setBackground(buttonBackground);
        btnInfo.setBackground(buttonBackground);
        txtIncome.setBackground(textBackground);
        txtPayable.setBackground(textBackground);
        txtStatus.setBackground(textBackground);
        txtIncome.setForeground(textForeground);
        txtPayable.setForeground(textForeground);
        txtStatus.setForeground(textForeground);
    }
}

private final ButtonColorScheme greenAndGrey = new ButtonColorScheme(
    new Color(127,191,95), new Color(159, 191, 143), new Color(201, 255, 191), new Color(89, 89, 89));     

private final ButtonColorScheme redAndBlack = new ButtonColorScheme(
    new Color(191,120,95), new Color(202, 160, 143), new Color(255, 180, 191), Color.BLACK);

public void btnGreenActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
   greenAndGrey.apply();
}

public void btnRedActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
   redAndBlack.apply();
}
```

Comment: Good idea but this code won't work. I'll upvote you when you fix it

Comment: @nachokk Yeah, I just realised I had incorrectly made it static.  Is that the bug you're referring to?  If I've made another mistake, please tell me what it is.

Comment: @DavidWallace Is the `private static final` supposed to be static? having errors with those lines.

Comment: @JakeB I edited those two lines shortly after I first posted them.  Did you pick up the updated version?  If you have, then tell me what your error message is please.

Comment: @DavidWallace "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"

EDIT: at both the 'GREEN_AND_GREY' and 'RED_AND_BLACK' lines of code.

Comment: Whoops.  OK, drop the `static`.  Sorry.

Comment: My apologies for having a handful of errors, and then editing them away.  I really should have tested all of this before I posted it; but it would have meant writing your entire panel first.  Sorry again.

Comment: @DavidWallace no need to be sorry! :D
Thankyou I got it sorted now.

Answer (score 1):

Methods are quite useful in such cases. Place this code into a method.
Add whatever parameters needed (e.g. you may decide to turn these values
159, 191, 143, etc. into parameters of the method say named r,g,b). Then
just call your method with the arguments you need (e.g. with r=166, g=202, b=192).

Answer (score 1):

Just create a method,

```
private void setWidgetColors(Color ... colours){
    int i=0;
    Color btnGrn = i++ <= colours.length?colours[i-1]:new Color(159, 191, 143);          //Sets the colour to a class
    Color txtGrn = i++ <= colours.length?colours[i-1]:new Color(201, 255, 191);          //Sets the colour to a class
    Color txtGry = i++ <= colours.length?colours[i-1]:new Color(89, 89, 89);       

         //Sets the colour to a class
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(i++ <= colours.length ? colours[3] : new Color(127,191,95)); //Sets background color to green
    btnConvert.setBackground(btnGrn);                 //Changes the colors to green
    btnReset.setBackground(btnGrn);                   //Changes the colors to green
    btnClose.setBackground(btnGrn);                   //Changes the colors to green
    btnInfo.setBackground(btnGrn);                    //Changes the colors to green
    txtIncome.setBackground(txtGrn);                  //Changes the colors to green
    txtPayable.setBackground(txtGrn);                 //Changes the colors to green
    txtStatus.setBackground(txtGrn);                  //Changes the colors to green
    txtIncome.setForeground(txtGry);                  //Changes the colors to grey
    txtPayable.setForeground(txtGry);                 //Changes the colors to grey
    txtStatus.setForeground(txtGry);                  //Changes the colors to grey
}
```

And then

```
private void btnGreenActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
    Color btnGrn = new Color(159, 191, 143);          //Sets the colour to a class
    Color txtGrn = new Color(201, 255, 191);          //Sets the colour to a class
    Color txtGry = new Color(89, 89, 89);
    Color backgroundColor = new Color(127,191,95); 
    setWidgetColors(btnGrn,txtGrn,txtGry,backgroundColor);
}
```

Comment: @DavidWallace He copy-pasted OP's code. I don't see why he should have fixed it :p

Comment: @DavidWallace just copy paste i didn't see if he use it or not, just remove

Comment: How about `setWidgetColors()` or `colorWidgets()`?